# Плавное закрытие окна аккордеона

Tags: javascript, css

Пытаюсь сделать плавное закрытие окна аккордеона. При раскрытии все происходит плавно, а вот при закрытии все тут же исчезает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
const accButton = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
const accWindow = document.querySelectorAll('.acc-window');
accButton.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const clicked = e.target;
    const data = clicked.dataset.number
    const clickedModal = document.querySelector(`.acc-window-${data}`)
    clickedModal.classList.toggle('acc-window__active');
    if (clickedModal.style.maxHeight) {
        clickedModal.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
        clickedModal.style.maxHeight = clickedModal.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
});
```

```
.acc-window
    background: white
    border: .1rem solid #efeeee
    width: 56rem
    right: 0
    top: 7rem
    max-height: 0
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out
    display: none
    overflow: hidden

    &__active
        display: block
        margin-bottom: 2rem
```

Comment: Потому-что при закрытии сразу пропадает `display: block` и становиться `display: none`.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо